# Where can I see the "official" texts of BIP 100 and 102?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, block-size-increase

I only see BIP 101 officially at https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0101.mediawiki.  Is there a reason that 100 and 102 don't show up here as well?  Couldn't they all just be listed as drafts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BIP 102 was submitted as Pull Request, which you can see here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6451

The latest draft of BIP 100 that I could find was here:
http://gtf.org/garzik/bitcoin/BIP100-blocksizechangeproposal.pdf
but it might be out of date.